# Mot ou locution quand le remède est (supposé) pire que le mal?

Tags: choix-de-mot, locutions

Je cherche un mot ou une expression pour decrire une situation où un problème est identifié, une solution à ce probleme est élaboré et mise en application mais que finalement, les effets de cette solution sont pires, et aggravent la situation initiale.

Il y a de nombreux exemples de cela en politique et en économie. Ma question provient d'une discussion sur le "CV anonyme": en France, il est documenté qu'il est plus difficile de trouver un emploi lorsque l'on est issu de l'immigration ou que l'on vient d'une cité sensible. D'où l'idée d'obliger les entreprises à accepter des CV anonymes, i.e. sans nom, photo ni adresse. C'est une idée qui semble raisonnable mais s'il n'y a pas d'obligation au CV anonyme pour le candidat, cela risque d'aggraver le probleme: si j'anonymise mon CV, le recruteur risque de me catégoriser comme "Arabe de banlieue" (avec le prejugé de délinquant potentiel qui lui est attaché), et ne jamais considerer mon parcours academique et professionel.

Veuillez noter que quand je parle d'expression pour décrire cette situation, je ne parle pas de proverbe, mais de locution (comme "effet X" par exemple). "Effet boomerang" est proche de ce que je veux mais pas tout à fait satisfaisant (la victime des consequences négatives de la solution en est son initiateur, ce qui n'est pas a priori le cas dans ce que je cherche).

Answer (score 3):

Dans le cadre d'une discussion de proposition de loi, on pourra arguer que :

> Adopter cette loi sera *un remède pire que le mal*.

Pour être plus catégorique suite à une décision néfaste :

> C'est *se tirer une balle dans le pied*.

Answer (score 2):

Ce que tu décris correspond à ce qu'on appelle en sociologie « **l'effet pervers** ».

> On nomme effet pervers un résultat non désiré et fâcheux d'une action qui se retourne contre les intentions de ceux qui l'ont engagée, selon la formule « l'enfer est pavé de bonnes intentions ».
> [...]
> Le fonctionnement est en général le suivant : on établit qu'une action va avoir un résultat heureux. Malheureusement, on oublie souvent que ce résultat n'est obtenu que toutes choses égales par ailleurs, or, très souvent, l'action a pour effet de modifier les conditions initiales, de sorte que le résultat obtenu est différent de celui prévu. ([Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effet_pervers))

Le [sociologue Raymond Boudon](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Boudon) a étudié l'effet pervers dans on livre *Effets pervers et ordre social* et on pourrait résumer sa thèse ainsi :

> L'effet pervers se définit comme une action non voulue par un individu, une institution quelconque ou bien l'ensemble d'une société. Selon Raymond Boudon, «on peut dire qu'il y a effet pervers lorsque deux individus (ou plus) en recherchant un objectif donné engendrent un état de choses non recherché et qui peut être indésirable du point de vue de chacun des deux, soit de l'un deux».
>
> Au niveau individuel, on peut classer les embouteillages et les files d'attente comme des effets pervers; l'agrégation des désirs personnels aboutit dans ces deux cas à des effets indésirables pour l'ensemble des usagers. Au niveau institutionnel, l'augmentation de la demande d'éducation provoque une hausse des coûts personnels et collectifs et une dévalorisation générale des diplômes. Au niveau de l'ensemble d'une société, l'inflation est un bel exemple d'effet pervers; tous les membres de la société d'une façon directe ou indirecte alimentent, sans se consulter, l'ennemi socio-économique le plus important des sociétés industrielles.  [*L'encyclopédie de l'Agora*](http://agora.qc.ca/documents/systeme--effets_pervers_et_systeme_scolaire_par_jean_stafford)

Quelques exemples d'emplois en contexte :

- > La solitude progresse : effet pervers du “chacun pour soi” ? [*Boulevard Voltaire*](http://www.bvoltaire.fr/mariedelarue/solitude-progresse-effet-pervers-du-soi,93023)
- > Si les allocations chômage ont un effet pervers, c'est parce qu'elles incitent les employeurs à proposer des salaires plus élevés pour être sûrs d'attirer des candidats.  [*Les Echos*](http://www.lesechos.fr/23/10/2013/LesEchos/21549-023-ECH_vif-debat-sur-l-effet-pervers-des-allocations-chomage.htm)
- > la réduction des dépenses de l’Etat de 50 milliards d’euros d’ici à 2017 [...] risque toutefois d'avoir un effet pervers sur l’emploi et la croissance dans le pays [...]  [*Le journal de l'économie*](http://www.journaldeleconomie.fr/Le-plan-d-economies-du-gouvernement-aurait-un-effet-pervers-sur-emploi-et-croissance_a1126.html)

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait parler familièrement de *retour de flamme* ou de *retour de manivelle*, mais leur sens est peut-être un peu trop proche d'*effet boomerang*.

Answer (score 0):

On dit parfois **« jeter le bébé avec l'eau du bain »**.

Même si ce n'est pas à proprement parler un proverbe, c'est du registre courant ou familier, et j'ignore si ça peut correspondre à ton contexte, mais il fallait le mentionner car on y retrouve une signification très proche : la "solution" employée résout le problème tout en causant un tort bien supérieur au problème de départ.